# Finding a vector that minimizes an error

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Having

$\mathbf{E}_{M\times 1} = \mathbf{T}_{M\times 1} - \mathbf{Q}_{M\times L}\times \mathbf{P}_{L\times 1}$

Where the subscripts are the size of the matrices and I know $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, I want to find $\mathbf{P}$ such that $\mathbf{E}$ is minimum.

I know that this problem has already been dealt with but I can't remember how to solve it. I guess I should use the MSE to minimize $\mathbf{E}$ though I'm not completely confident.

The problem I'm dealing with is: $\mathbf{T}$ is a row-vector of totals (dollars), $\mathbf{Q}$ is a matrix of quantities of products and $\mathbf{P}$ is a column-vector of prices. So the element $k$ of $\mathbf{T}$ is the total that client $k$ paid (there are $M$ clients), the row $k$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ is the amount of products ($L$ different products) that client $k$ bought, and the column-vector $\mathbf{P}$ contains the prices of each product.

What I don't know is the price of each product, so my approach to estimate it is trying to minimize $\mathbf{E}$. I'm explaining this because perhaps the MSE is not the best function to try to minimize, or perhaps there's a better approach.

Edit: I'm looking for an adaptive way of doing this, as the matrices are huge and calculating and inverse is not feasible.

Comment: Solve the [normal equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html) $$\rm Q^\top Q \, p = \rm Q^\top t$$

Comment: I'm looking for an adaptive way, as calculating the inverse is very costly or even impossible (the list of clients is extremely huge)

Comment: Just use Gaussian elimination!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo So I assume I've focused the problem the wrong way. When is adaptive linear estimation used, then?

Comment: I don't know what "adaptive linear estimation" is. If you want something iterative, you can use gradient descent $$\mathrm p_{k+1} = \mathrm p_k - \gamma \, \mathrm Q^\top (\mathrm Q \, \mathrm p_k - \mathrm t)$$ where $\rm p_k$ is the estimate of $\rm p$ at step $k$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo there is not a fixed list of prices. We are selling virtual goods and we've been doing it at "random" prices, so I'm actually trying to infer a price for our products from the data we have. What I'm trying to say is that I won't get perfect results as if it was a simple system of equations, that's why I have focused the problem this way (from an 'estimation point of view').

Comment: Start with an initial guess $\mathrm p_0$ and then iterate. Note that $\gamma$ must be chosen carefully to ensure convergence.